# BreezeJs with standard REST and Json Patch

Tags: breeze

we currently have a project where we will use a standard RESTful Interface implemented in WebApi. So there will not be a single Breeze-Controller with a single SaveChanges method to handle all CUD request. Instead, there will be a Controller by type Web Api implementation where the CRUD Actions will be handled by each Controller. Additionally, we think of using JSON Patch to just send the needed data to the backend.

Is there any Adapter already implemented for BreezeJs? There is a abstractrest implementation in breeze labs which sounds like the right base class. But this should be something other already encountered. Is there an example or implementation we could use for our needs?

Thank you for your help!

Marc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are far from the only person who could benefit from such an adapter. I've been meaning to write about this topic for ... well I think it is years now. It's strange that not enough people have asked to push me over the hump.

You're on the right path with the `AbstractRestDataServiceAdapter` in Breeze Labs.

I recently wrote a derived adapter to do pretty much what you have in mind ... although I was targeting the Web API (aka MVC6) in ASP.NET 5. Take a look at this ["mvc6-unicorn" adapter](https://github.com/wardbell/UnicornStore/blob/DevIntersections/CompletedSource/UnicornStore/src/UnicornStore/wwwroot/app/unicorn.breeze.dataservice.adapter.js) for inspiration.

It uses POST for modified entities but you could use PATCH or MERGE as in this fragment from the "OData" adapter in [*b00_breeze.dataService.odata.js*](https://github.com/Breeze/breeze.js/blob/master/src/b00_breeze.dataService.odata.js).

```
else if (aspect.entityState.isModified()) {
    ...
    request.method = "MERGE";
    request.data = helper.unwrapChangedValues(entity, entityManager.metadataStore, transformValue);
} ...
```

Please note also that the client-side interpretation of the JSON data within the `JsonResultsAdapter` is greatly facilitated by a small amount of server-side Json.NET reconfiguration along the lines of what you see in this [`ApiConfiguration` class here](https://github.com/wardbell/UnicornStore/blob/DevIntersections/CompletedSource/UnicornStore/src/UnicornStore/ApiConfiguration.cs) (that's the MVC6 equivalent to *WebApiConfig*).

Sadly, I have to leave you here with only these clues to craft a solution that works for you.

The full story ... which I do hope to write "soon" ... belongs in our Breeze documentation.

Please feel free to return if you get stuck on specific points.